# Differing element types in jQuery select

Tags: jquery, dom

I've got two HTML forms, A and B, each with an input tag. Find below the HTML elements as copied out of the *element view* from Chrome's developer window.

**Form A:**

```
<input type="text" id="idToken1" name="callback_0" value="" data-validator="required"
   required="" data-validator-event="keyup" class="form-control input-lg" 
   placeholder="" autofocus="">
```

**Form B:**

```
<input lightning-input_input="" type="text" id="input-10" class="slds-input">
```

In the developer console when the DOM has been rendered, I can select both of them like this

```
 $('input[type=text]')
```

However, the return types differ. While the first seems to be a node/element/jQuery function, the second seems to be just plain text. Find screenshots below with some functions called on the respective select.

**Form A:**

[image: an HTML snippet with a single input tag]

**Form B:**

[image: another HTML snippet with a different input tag]

Since the WebAPI is a complete riddle to me, can somebody explain why the return types differ? And eventually, since a Protractor e2e test fails setting an email address to the input field, how to write a value into the input field of Form B?

Comment: To people with visual impairment, screen readers, and search engines, your question's middle section reads "Form A: enter image description here. Form B: enter image description here." Not the greatest experience. Whereas, if you just copied the text from the console and pasted it here, as code, everyone would be able to understand what was under discussion.

Comment: Regarding the question, for some reason, the second set of code is returning the `HTMLInputElement` instead of the jQuery object. This is likely due to jQuery not being included on that page. Something else could be supplying `$` as a shortcut for `document.querySelector`.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of the image descriptor!! I have to admit I have overlooked that all along. Good hint, I'm gonna inspect the missing jQuery libs.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you are right, the $ in Form B seems to be provided by Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities Thanks!